# How to start a batch file when a text file is created?

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to work out how to run a batch file when a text file is created. I have tried to research but am unable to find anything that helps.
The Pseudocode of what I want is something like this:

When "Response.txt" is created run "2 Week.bat".

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off

:start_loop
    if exist "c:\Response.txt" ( 
        start cmd /c "c:\2weeks.bat"
        goto :exodus
    )
    rem :: wait for 1 minute
    w32tm /stripchart /computer:localhost /period:1 /dataonly /samples:60  >nul 2>&1

goto :start_loop
:exodus
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work on Vista and later:

```
@echo off
:loop
    if exist "c:\folder\Response.txt" "c:\folder\2 week.bat"
    rem - reduce CPU usage by waiting for 15 seconds
    timeout /t 15 /nobreak
goto :loop
```